# jQuery/PHP for top notification bars that push all page content down

Tags: php, jquery, notifications

Disclaimer: Ok, so I know it's super easy to make a top notification bar by hiding a div w/ jQuery at the top of the page and add an event handler to it.

Dilemma: I need to incorporate a notification bar on a page that has the bg image set to the body, so when you show() a div at the top it pushes all content down w/o pushing the bg down and throws off the entire site. I'm trying to avoid wrapping all the content in a div and switching the bg css over to that div in fear of throwing off other child element's styles.

If anyone is aware of method to push ALL page content down (including the  content) I would greatly appreciate any wisdom.

Comment: What do you mean throw off the entire site? Do you have a demo or a fiddle?

Comment: The two answers you have below will solve your problem.  It's hard to upvote either one because the way the question is phrased makes it a bit ambiguous. If you WANT the background to move, in relation to the existing content, use the use the $('body').preprend('#notice') method; if you do NOT WANT the background to move, in relation to the existing content, use the margin-top method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `margin-top` on the body element and `background-position` to offset the background image.

```
$('#note').show(); // absolute positioned at top of page
$('body').css({marginTop: '50px', backgroundPosition: '0 50px'});
```

Comment: @rkw My apologies if I presented the question with any ambiguity. I tried the prepend() function as you suggested (both w/ body and html) and both times it shifted the content down w/o shifting the bg. Derek Hunziker, I ended up using your .css method and it ended up pushing my bg down and allowed me to achieve what I was attempting to accomplish. Thank you all for the input!

Comment: better late than never! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might try prepending the div to the top of your content using jQuerys .prependTo() . This way the new div element will naturally be before everything, and then you can also style the element easily. This should allow your background to remain in the same position as well.

Comment: That won't also move the background, like the person who asked the question wanted.